# Passing the variable to external file

Tags: javascript, php

Here what I am trying to do. There is a function in my file.php, which loads external file. I want add the ID of the user to the URL. This script loads the contents of the file:

```
public function setExternalSolutionScriptsToBuffer() {
    // Get dictionary   
    $externalSolutions = file_get_contents($this->getExternalTargetingSolutionsJsUrl());

    // Composer the ouput buffer
    $this->outputBuffer .= "\n";
    $this->outputBuffer .= $externalSolutions;
    $this->outputBuffer .= "\n";
}
```

There is also a function for the ID:

```
public function setExposureOfUserIdScriptToBuffer() {
    $user_id = $this->visitor->getOnlineId();
}
```

What i need is to pass that variable to the external file, and attach it to the end of the src URL of this script:

```
(function () {
    if (location.protocol.substr(0,5)==='http:') {
        try {
            (function () {
                var d = document;
                var e = d.createElement('script');
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                e.src = 'http://example.com/some.js?uid=' + ***user_id***;
                e.async = true;
                (d.head || d.body || d.firstChild).appendChild(e);
            })();
        } catch (e) {}
    }
})();
```

So the variable would be added to the URL and the src would look like 'http://example.com/some.js?uid=4234234324'

Comment: ah wait missunderstood - how about `file_get_contents` and `str_replace` on `***user_id***`

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean for me to have better udnerstanding ?

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty - assuming that $externalSolutions is the src of the JS

```
$userID = 1234;
$externalSolutions = file_get_contents(..js-file..);
$externalSolutions = str_replace('***user_id***', $userID, $externalSolutions);
echo "<script>\n",$externalSolutions,"\n</script>\n";
```